# How does atomic seq_cst memory order actually work?

Tags: c++, memory-barriers, lock-free, stdatomic, spinlock

For example, there are shared variables.

```
int val;
Cls obj;
```

An atomic bool variable acts as a data indicator.

```
std::atomic_bool flag = false;
```

Thread 1 only set these variables.

```
while (flag == true) { /* Sleep */ }

val = ...;
obj = ...;

flag = true; /* Set flag to true after setting shared variables. */
```

Thread 2 only get these variables.

```
while (flag != true) { /* Sleep */ }

int local_val = val;
Cls local_obj = obj;

flag = false; /* Set flag to false after using shared variables. */
```

My questions are:

1. For `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, which is default for `std::atomic_bool`, is it safe to set or get shared variables after `while (...) {}`?
2. Using `bool` instead of `std::atomic_bool` is correct or not?

Comment: Using `memory_order_seq_cst` is sufficient, and in fact stronger than what you need for this case. `acquire` on load and `release` on write are sufficient. Although, I wouldn't recommend using the atomic variable for a mutex - you'd better use proper `mutex` and `condition_variable` in almost all cases.

Comment: You tagged this [lock-free], but you're using atomic to implement a spinlock.  That's the opposite of a lock-free algorithm.  Consider a SeqLock if you want lock-free writes, and usually-cheap reads that are truly read-only.  (Assuming that `Cls` is too large to be lock-free itself, otherwise that's even better)

Comment: @PeterCordes OK. I think I have some mis-understanding of lock-free. It is actually a spin lock. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The building blocks are individually lock-free, like atomic RMW, but the overall algorithm you built out of them is a lock.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm covers the taxonomy of non-blocking algorithms.

Comment: @ALX23z There is the case we use atomic instead of cond and mutex: we want to print some logs during waiting, especially during long time waiting, which helps us to identify program state.

Comment: @guanboshen in this case you just use `wait_for` or `wait_until` with a time limit. I'd recommend usage of atomics only in dedicated and optimized multi-threaded algos (well there is also simple use case for counters - used for shared pointers and the like).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, the code is fine, and as ALX23z says, it would still be fine if all the loads of `flag` were `std::memory_order_acquire` and all the stores were `std::memory_order_release`.  The extra semantics that `std::memory_order_seq_cst` provides are only relevant to observing the ordering between loads and stores to two or more different atomic variables.  When your whole program only has one atomic variable, it has no useful effect.

   Roughly, the idea is that acquire/release suffice to ensure that the accesses to your non-atomic variables really do happen in between the load/store of the atomic `flag`, and do not "leak out".  More formally, you could use the C++11 memory model axioms to prove that given any read of the objects in thread 1, and any write of the objects in thread 2, one of them happens before the other.  The details are a little tedious, but the key idea is that an acquire load and a release store is exactly what you need to get *synchronization*, which is how you get a happens-before relation between operations in two different threads.
2. No, if you replace the `atomic_bool` with a plain `bool` then your code has undefined behavior.  You would then be reading and writing all your variables in different threads, with no mutexes or atomic variables that could possibly create synchronization, and that is the definition of a data race.

Comment: https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ is a nice intro to the concept of acquire and release semantics.  Some recent CSS change seems to have shrunk / cropped the diagrams that were a key part of the post, though, or maybe that's just my DarkReader using a dark background making them look bad.

Comment: This is very clear explanation: "ensure that the accesses to your non-atomic variables really do happen in between the load/store of the atomic flag". Thank you!